# How to avoid "failed to allocate memory(NoMemory Error) with Axlsx gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

The purpose of this script convert csv files into one xlsx file. i have 33 csv files each csv file consists with 1229 columns,289 rows, while i am trying to read all those csv files into one xlsx file i got following error

> cell_serializer.rb:138:in 'value_serialization':failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)

i thoght one file is too big to involve all data, so i decided to divide into two .xlsx files, but i got the same error. following is the script i am using.

```
require 'axlsx'

def csv_to_xlsx(xlsx_file_name,file_names,p)
 file_names.each do | f |
 i = 0
 CSV.foreach(f) do |row|
   if i == 0
     p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => File.basename(f)) do | sheet |
       sheet.add_row row
     end
   elsif
     p.workbook.sheet_by_name(File.basename(f)).add_row row
   end
   i = i+1
 end
 p.serialize(xlsx_file_name)
 end
end

csv_files = Dir.glob("./csv_file/*")
file_count = 0
file_names1 = Array.new
file_names2 = Array.new
csv_files.each do | f |
  file_count = file_count+1
  if file_count < 16
    file_names1 << f
  elsif
    file_names2 << f
  end
end

package1 = Axlsx::Package.new
package2 = Axlsx::Package.new
csv_to_xlsx('./xls_file/data01.xlsx',file_names1,package1)
csv_to_xlsx('./xls_file/data02.xlsx',file_names2,package2)
```

To achieve what i want , i tried spreadsheed it works great and simple to use, but it only creates .xls file which can`t contain more than 256 columns.

any idea to avoid NoMemory error, appreciate you help in advance.

my ruby version is 2.3.0p0

Answer (score 0):

I did divide those csv files into more than 2 .xlsx files and it solves the problem. but it is best if i can write those all csv files into one .xlsx file.